# AWS S3 в качестве HTTP сервера

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

хотел организовать CDN для игрового лаунчера. Но нереальное количество документации по вэбу сбило меня с толку. Хотелось бы знать как правильно организовать CDN чтобы он работал как банальный FTP. Чтобы я мог по HTTP-ссылке скачать пак с игрой. Попытался настроить все через cyberduck, но в попытке скачать папку или отдельный файл меня ждали лишь ошибки по типу "AccessDenied"(При скачивании одного файла) или "PermanentRedirect" в случае если пытаюсь скачать папку. Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: Еще посмотрите в сторону Selectel. Там немного проще настройки. Так,  в качестве альтернативы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб файл был доступен для публичного доступа у него права должны быть проставлены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Впрочем, сам бакет тоже должен быть публичный:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня эти права доступа выданы для всего бакета.

Comment: @HoneyCake при загрузке по дефолту у файла нет прав на публичное чтение. Это нужно либо при загрузке дополнительно указывать(не знаю, как в FTP клиенте, но при загрузке в S3 средствами php нужно было параметры передавать дополнительные), либо на странице в aws на конкретный файл задавать права.

Comment: Даже сейчас попытался сделать пермишен для всех, для одного файла, та же ситуация. Но меня больше интересует скачивание целостной папки.

Comment: А при скачивании папки выдает такую ошибку. <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>